# Return my email adress in linux by TCL/csh command

Tags: linux, email, tcl

I write script in TCL and want to get my email address.
Is there any way to get my email address?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're lucky and it's in an environment variable, there's no way to get that unless you've provided for it in an explicit setting. In terms of standard ones, the `USER` or `LOGNAME` environment variables might be set (the latter is more email-address-like) but neither have the hostname for making a full mailbox address, as that's often different from the local machine name (and DNS might not have a helpful record). Plus a lot of people have email addresses that are just totally different from their local username and machine name. How is anyone to guess that someone is `joe.schmoe.1234567890` at `gmail` without being told explicitly when their local username is just `js` or `js2000`?

Ask explicitly, either interactively (this gets annoying if used a lot) or through setting something. Could be in a configuration file, via a command line argument, or an environment variable.

---

```
# Interactive on the terminal
puts -nonewline "Email address: "
flush stdout
gets stdin email
```

```
# From a command line argument; use the argv global list
set email [lindex $argv 1]
# Probably need more complex parsing than that
```

```
# From an environment variable
set email $env(USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
```

```
# From a simple setting file, in this case holding a Tcl dictionary
set f [open "my.setting.file.txt"]
set data [read $f]
close $f
set email [dict get $data "email"]
```

Comment: There are far more ways of doing it than these, depending on platform and application.